# Layout Algorithms in JUNG

Tags: java, graph, jung

I want to visualize a graph from my Java application, to do so I use JUNG.The thing is that my graphs include a bulk of nodes and edges,which of the Layouts provided by JUNG can give me minimum cross edging? so that the graph looks better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JUNG layouts don't try to minimize edge crossings per se, as that's an O(E^2) proposition at best.

I recommend you try out the different layouts and see which works for you.  There's no single right answer that works for everyone.